# One row with array of IDs or one row per ID?

Tags: database, parse-platform, database-design

I'm working on a video app with a "Feed" view which lists all of the video published by the users I follow.

I want to implement a "viewed" state on these videos and was wondering what would be the best way to achieve that.

*I'm using Parse (self-hosted on my server) but I think my question is common to every DB systems.*

My idea was to create a class (in my Parse backend) named "VideoView" in which I would do one of these options :

**Option 1)** Insert one row each time I will see a particular video. 
So in this class, I would have a pointer to the User class (an `objectId` of the current user who has viewed the video) and a pointer to the Video class (an `objectId` of the video viewed).

**Option 2)** Insert one row per user (with again, a pointer to the User class) and have an array of each video ids this particular user has viewed.

What would be the best option to achieve what I want here ? What is the best practice in this case - saving one row per video view OR saving one row per user and save each video ids viewed in an array ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a normalized database design, option 1.  If you're using a NoSQL database, you may use option 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many mapping. An user can have any number of videos viewed and a video can be viewed by any number of user.

Best option is have a table mapping from userId, videoId this way you can answer more queries related to user and videos. Instead of traversing whole array whenever a query comes for number of views for particular video for each user you can simply query count to db.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think I should use the one "Gilbert Le Blanc" gave me in a comment. I have also read that in a NoSQL case, my option 2 is the best bet!